# Google FCM on phonegap and localhost

Tags: php, localhost, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Is it possible for FCM to work properly if the application is still under development using phonegap / cordova?

- Not yet in playstore
- Do not have a domain yet
- Only on localhost

If so, why do I always get the "MismatchSenderId" alert when I try to send a message with PHP code?

Comment: Update: Finally I tried to make the project first in google play console, and yes the new FCM will be active after registering API KEY.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit the word "solved" into the question title.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, thanks...